# How to read UInt32 numbers of bytes with binary reader?

Tags: c#, binaryreader, uint32

I need my code to do something like this - Somewhere in the code `num` gets a value and after that i want to read from file EXACTLY as bytes is the number `num`.

For example: If num is 39382 i need to read 39382 bytes and place them into byte[] buffer;

Before I had something like this:

```
ushort num = 0;
//....  num get some value;
byte[] buffer = bRead.ReadBytes(num);
```

Now I have to change it so that `num` is a `UInt32`, but then `ReadBytes` doesn't work(because it wants int32). It's possible 'num' to exceeds int32. I fixed it like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[num];
for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
{
    buffer[j] = bRead.ReadByte();
}
```

and it works but I am wondering is that the best way of doing it? Or there is another?

Comment: Warning: allocating a >2GB array will only work on .NET 4.5 64bit with `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` set to true. You might want to work with a `FileStream` or equivalent instead.

Comment: And thats one of the reasons i want to change it with better one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that num won't go beyond the int32 max you can use the following:

```
UInt32 num = 0;
//....  num get some value;
bRead.ReadBytes(checked((int)num));
```

This will throw an OverflowException if num goes beyond the signed 32 bit max.

Comment: If I know it won't beyond int32 max value I was going to make it int.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
public static ushort ToUInt32(
    byte[] value,
    int startIndex
)
```

you specify the source array and the position where the encoded number starts. If your byte array contains a single number, `startIndex` will be 0, and the length must be at least 4.